# php web image search

Tags: php

I want to do a picture search engine. I use `simple_html_dom` and `preg_match_all` to get all the images, then use `getimagesize` to get all the image sizes. 
Here is one part of my code.

```
<?php
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$v = 'http://www.jqueryimage.com/';
$html = file_get_html($v);
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
        if( preg_match('#^http:\/\/(.*)\.(jpg|gif|png)$#i',$element->src)){
            $image = $element->src;
            //$arr = getimagesize($image); //get image width and height            
            //$imagesize = $arr[0] * $arr[1];  
            echo $image.'<hr />';
        }
    }
?>
```

First question, how to add a judgement so that I can echo the biggest size image? (only one image).

Second question, I can get the image real url in these two possibilities, first where image is as a 'http' began, second where image is as a `/` began. 
But how to get the image real url in the situation where image is as a './' or `../` or `../../` began? it is difficulty for me to judge how many `../` in a image, then cut the site url to complement a image real url?

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean under 'biggest'? E.g. 200x200, 1024x1, 10x1000... Which one is the biggest of these 3? Do you want to calculate size of its surface area?

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, 200x200=`40000`, 1024x1=`1024`, 10x1000=`10000`, 200x200 is the biggest one. If there have move images are same size in the biggest `40000`, get the first one. thanks.

Comment: Exactly what I meant. Look at my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this before `foreach` loop:

```
$maxsize = -1;
$the_biggest_image = false;
```

Insert this below `$image = $element->src;` line

```
$arr = getimagesize($image);
if (($arr[0] * $arr[1]) > $maxsize) {
  $maxsize = $arr[0] * $arr[1];
  $the_biggest_image = $image;
  }
```

After `foreach` loop you'll have `$the_biggest_image` variable set or false if nothing found. This will take first one if more than one 'biggest image' found.

For second question, I don't know!

*Edit: fixed something!*

Comment: thanks, it can work. for the  second question, I will make a new question.